# How are pandas data frames stored in memory?

Tags: python, pandas

In particular, when I create a DataFrame by concatenating two Pandas Series objects, does Python create a new memory location and store copies of the series', or does it just create references to the two series?

If it just makes references, then would modifying the series like `series.name = "new_name"` affect the column names of the DataFrame?

Also, would getting a series from a DataFrame like `series = df['column_name']` take O(1) time or O(n) time?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A quick test shows that the cost is in the concat, vs. the dereference. So, BLUF, df['s1'] is O(1) while concat is O(n).

Running from 1 single item per series to 40 million per series, the dereference takes a similar amount of time, while the concat time seems to increase linearly.

using this simple code:

```
def func(frange):

    a1 = []
    a2 = []
    for x in numpy.arange(frange):
        a1.append(x)
        a2.append(-x)
        
    s1 = pd.Series(a1, index=a1, name='s1')
    s2 = pd.Series(a2, index=a1, name='s2')
    cstart =  time.perf_counter();
    df = pd.concat([s1, s2], axis=1)
    cend = time.perf_counter();
    
    tstart =  time.perf_counter();
    for y in range(100):
        series = df['s1']
        series2 = df['s2']
    tend = time.perf_counter();
    
    print (frange, ',', cend-cstart,tend-tstart)
```

the results are:

[image]